# Excel - Logical Formula puzzle

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, nested, logical-operators

I need to come up with a formula under highlighted "Result" column (see embedded SCREENSHOT) that should assign either 1 or 0 to the cell for each row. The criteria for the formula is:

- IF an incident has multiple "Str Types" (i call them legs) AND some of those legs say "Yes" and some of them say "No" to "Control Exist?" THEN "Result" should say 0.
- IF an incident has multiple "Str Types" (i call them legs) AND all of those legs say "Yes" to "Control Exist?" THEN "Result" should say 0.
- IF an incident has multiple "Str Types" (i call them legs) AND all of those legs say "No" to "Control Exist?" THEN "Result" should say 1. HOWEVER, that 1 value should be stated only ONCE per unique Incident ID.
- IF an incident does NOT have multiple "Str Types" (i call them legs) but only one AND it say "Yes" to "Control Exist?" THEN "Result" should say 0.
- IF an incident does NOT have multiple "Str Types" (i call them legs) but only one AND it say "No" to "Control Exist?" THEN "Result" should say 1.

I inserted a screenshot of the issue and the desired results are stated manually under "Result" column. I need a formula that will provide the same results.

Thanks for all you do!

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkjwi.png)

Comment: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) is not a site where you post a list of requirements and someone does your work for you. If you are unwilling to show what you've attempted *working or not( then I suggest you move your post to [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab).

Comment: =IF(AND(B2=B3,AD2<>AD3),0,IF(AND(B2=B3,AD2="No",AD3="No"),1,0))

Comment: this didn't help, hence i posted the criteria only to not misguide the people here.

Comment: A combination of COUNTIF() and COUNTIFS() will tell you if there are multiple legs.  It's not clear if you mean "multiple *distinct*" legs or just that there are multiple rows for that incident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made this **much** harder than it needs to be - If you look at your rules, you can re-state them as follows:

- Result = `0` for ALL Values except for:

  - First occurrence of "No" when there are no "Yes" values for that given `Incident Id`

So, taking your sample picture and placing that table in range `A1:C19`, your `Result` formula in column D would be as follows:

```
D2: =IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19,A2,$C$2:$C$19,"Yes")>=1,0,IF(A2<>A1,1,0))
```

Breaking it down:

`COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19,A2,$C$2:$C$19,"Yes")` - Count the number of `Yes` values for a given `Incident Id`

`IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19,A2,$C$2:$C$19,"Yes")>=1,0` - If we have at least 1 `Yes` for the given `Incident Id`, then set the value to `0`

`,IF(A2<>A1,1,0))` - Now we're in the ELSE portion, so that means there are no `Yes` values, so all we care about is that we're in the first row of an Incident Id, that means that the value in column A is new, so it won't equal the value above it. So, if the `Incident Id` is different than the value in the row above it, return `1`, else return `0`.

Drag this formula down column D and you're done.

Sometimes it helps to re-evaluate the problem - Hope this does the trick!

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to spend some time to understand your logic but it seems to work perfectly! Thanks again for your help. This is a work deliverable for me due tomorrow and w/o your help it would've prolly taken me several hours. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Glad it made sense. The biggest thing to remember is to see if there's an easier way to state the problem... With the original rules, it would have been a much worse / more complicated formula.